# how can I add menu button in telegram bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, telegram-bot, telegraf

how can I add Menu button in telegram bot using **telegraf**

menu button like this
[image: Menu]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site; however it doesn’t seem you’ve asked a question. [ask]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I create a **menu** button by add a new framework " *Grammy* "

first install grammy : `npm install grammy`

seconde add this code :

```
const { Bot } = require("grammy");
const bot = new Bot(BOT_TOKEN); // <-- place your bot token in this string
```

create list of commands :

```
bot.api.setMyCommands([
{ command: "start", description: "إبدأ من جديد" },
{ command: "help", description: "طلب مساعدة " },
{ command: "list", description: "القائمة " },
]);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this in two ways. Either by

- using the [`setMyCommands`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmycommands) method, or
- contacting [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather) to use its `/setcommands` command.

Comment: Be sure to restart the telegram app to see the menu appear

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, you can use BotFather and set it directly from there.

1. Open BotFather - https://t.me/BotFather
2. send him the command `/setcommands`

[image]

Comment: thanks, but we need how to coding this option